# How to select a UITextField with IBAction to make it FirstResponder?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, first-responder

I have implemented multiple `TextFields` in a static `TableViewController` like this:

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField11:UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField12:UITextField?
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        inputField11!.delegate = self
        inputField12!.delegate = self
        ...
        inputField11?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to implement a way to change the active `TextField` with an `IBAction`.
I have an `inputFieldDidChange` `IBAction` method implemented that works fine, triggered by "Editing Changed" in the storyboard:

```
@IBAction func inputFieldDidChange(inputField: UITextField?) {
    switch inputField {
        case inputField11:
            inputField12?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case inputField12:
            inputField13?.becomeFirstResponder()
        ...
}
```

But for some reason the same implementation method doesn't work for my `inputFieldSelected` method, triggered by "Touch Down":

```
@IBAction func inputFieldSelected(inputField: UITextField?) {
    switch inputField {
        case inputField11:
            inputField11?.becomeFirstResponder()
        case inputField12:
            inputField12?.becomeFirstResponder()
        ...
    }
}
```

I also tried doing this with "Touch Up Inside", "Editing Did Begin" and tap gesture recognizers.

Comment: This is rather confusing... if you tap in a text field, it becomes first responder. Why are you trying to add a "Touch" action to it?

Comment: Tapping the text fields without implementing some sort of touch action doesn't do anything in my case.

Comment: There is no touch interaction for all of the tableView except for the navbar.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you've done with your layout. You say you have *"multiple TextFields in a static TableViewController"* ... by default, tapping in a text field in a cell in a static table view controller ***will*** "activate" that text field - that is, it will become the first responder. What might you have done to prevent that? Did you disable User Interaction for some reason?